# how to correctly map a Set in a pojo for hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, mapping

I need to authenticate the user on my application, but I'm having some difficulties with the `@ElementCollection` mapping on the User class.

I'm using the example found on [this Spring Security tutorial](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-hibernate-annotation-example/) to build my application on, so most things shown here are quite similar to that.

The User class `Set<UserProfile>` was originally defined as:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "HRM_USER_USER_PROFILE", 
     joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, 
     inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID") })
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
// -- getter and setter
```

The `UserProfile` class as:

```
    @Column(name="type", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
```

And the `UserProfileType` enum as:

```
USER("USER"),
DBA("DBA"),
ADMIN("ADMIN");

String userProfileType;

private UserProfileType(String userProfileType){
    this.userProfileType = userProfileType;
}

public String getUserProfileType(){
    return userProfileType;
}
```

Which is already persisted on the database, but the `User` class can't read.

**EDIT - insert the `@ElementCollection` part**

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = UserProfile.class)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "HRM_USER_USER_PROFILE", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_profile") })
@Column(name = "user_profiles")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>(0);
```

What I noticed is that the `user_profiles` column on the user table is not created nor any other tables that might refer to this mapping.

Instead of running a SQL script loading UserProfileType, User and their relationship, I'm using a `@PostConstruct` bean to load default values on application start.

I expected to print out the complete user info but I get no information on the user profiles.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no single ElementCollection in the posted code. What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? "I'm having some difficulties" is not a sufficient description of your concrete problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the `@ElementCollection` part... editing now.

Comment: Why do you think you must add ElementCollection to this mapping? Have you read its javadoc? Do you understand what it's used for? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: OK, I think I might have misread something. And, what I am trying to achieve is a mapping of all user profiles a given user has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to keep the "Many-to-Many" mapping only on "UserProfile" class, because "ElementCollection" is used to join elements which aren't entities, in your case, you must use the "CollectionTable" annotation.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="HRM_USER_USER_PROFILE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_profile"))
@AttributeOverrides({
          @AttributeOverride(name="type", 
                             column=@Column(name="TYPE"))
        })
private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>(0);
```

"CollectionTable" annotation indicates the name of your collection and the join column, after that, "AttributesOverrides" annotation set the columns which are part of your collection, in this case, I just put the "Type" column, but you can add more.

```
... 
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="type", column=@Column(name="TYPE")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="otherColumn", column=@Column(name="OTHER_COLUMN"))
})
...
```

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.